# Transformation of vielbein and spin connection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry

I'm trying to derive the transformation of vielbein and spin connection under local Poincare transformation:
$$
\delta{e_{a}}^{\mu} = {e'_{a}}^{\mu} - {e_{a}}^{\mu} = (\Lambda^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}{e_{a}}^{\mu}-{e_{a}}^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}\Lambda^{\mu})+{\Lambda_{a}}^{b}{e_{b}}^{\mu},-(1)
$$
$$
\delta{\omega_{a}}^{bc} = {\omega'_{a}}^{bc}-{\omega_{a}}^{bc} =\Lambda^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}{\omega_{a}}^{bc}-{e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Lambda^{bc}+{\Lambda_{a}}^{d}{\omega_{d}}^{bc}+{\omega_{a}}^{db}{\Lambda_{d}}^{c}-{\omega_{a}}^{dc}{\Lambda_{d}}^{b}.\:-(2)
$$
Starting from the transformation of covariant derivative $\nabla_{a}$:
\begin{align}
\nabla_{a}\rightarrow\nabla_{a}' = e^{G}\nabla_{a}e^{-G},
\end{align}
with $\nabla_{a} = {e_{a}}^{\mu}(x)\partial_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}{\omega_{a}}^{bc}(x)M_{cb}$ and $G = \Lambda^{\mu}(x)\partial_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\Lambda^{ab}(x)M_{ba}$. I kept terms up to first order in $\Lambda^{\mu}$ and $\Lambda^{ab}$, getting
\begin{align}
\nabla_{a}' &= \nabla_{a}+[G, \nabla_{a}]\\&=\nabla_{a}+[\Lambda^{\mu}\partial_{\mu},{e_{a}}^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}]+\frac{1}{2}[\Lambda^{\mu}\partial_{\mu},{\omega_{a}}^{bc}M_{cb}]\\&+\frac{1}{2}[\Lambda^{cd}M_{dc}, {e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}]+\frac{1}{4}[\Lambda^{de}M_{ed},{\omega_{a}}^{bc}M_{cb}].
\end{align}
After calculating the 4 commutators above, there're two problems puzzled me:

1. I got almost all terms on the right hand side of (1) and (2). Yet the only term I couldn't get is ${\Lambda_{a}}^{d}{\omega_{d}}^{bc}$ in (2).
2. There are some extra terms which confused me.

Take one of the commutator for example,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}[\Lambda^{cd}M_{dc}, {e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}]&=\frac{1}{2}(\Lambda^{cd}M_{dc}{e_{a}}^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}({e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Lambda^{cd})M_{dc}\\
&+\frac{1}{2}{e_{a}}^{\mu}\Lambda^{cd}[M_{dc},\partial_{\mu}]\\&=\frac{1}{2}(\Lambda^{cd}M_{dc}{e_{a}}^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}({e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Lambda^{cd})M_{dc}\\&+\frac{1}{2}{e_{a}}^{\mu}\Lambda^{cd}(\eta_{c\mu}\partial_{d}-\eta_{d\mu}\partial_{c})\\&=\frac{1}{2}(\Lambda^{cd}M_{dc}{e_{a}}^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}({e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Lambda^{cd})M_{dc}+{e_{a}}^{\mu}\Lambda^{cd}\eta_{c\mu}\partial_{d}\\&=\frac{1}{2}(\Lambda^{cd}M_{dc}{e_{a}}^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}-\frac{1}{2}({e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Lambda^{cd})M_{dc}+{\Lambda_{a}}^{b}{e_{b}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}.
\end{align}
I can see that the second term of the above is identified as the second term of (2); and the last term of the above is identified as the last term of (1). However, I don't know how to deal with the first term of the above.
Similarly, I got $-\frac{1}{2}({\omega_{a}}^{bc}M_{cb}\Lambda^{\mu})\partial_{\mu}$ and $\Lambda_{c}{\omega_{a}}^{bc}\partial_{b}$ from $\frac{1}{2}[\Lambda^{ab}M_{ba}, {e_{a}}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}]$, also $\frac{1}{4}(\Lambda^{de}M_{ed}{\omega_{a}}^{bc})M_{cb}$ and  $-\frac{1}{4}({\omega_{a}}^{bc}M_{cb}\Lambda^{de})M_{ed}$ from $\frac{1}{4}[\Lambda^{de}M_{ed},{\omega_{a}}^{bc}M_{cb}]$. Those are the 5 extra terms which confused me.

I've checked repeatedly for the past few days. But I couldn't see the proble. Can someone point me out? Sorry for my messy typing.